# PHP / JQUERY / BARCODE SCANNER

Tags: java, php, jquery, barcode

i'm creating a webapp. for a customer and have a small issue.
It prints out orders with a barcode on it, which can be scanned again into the app.
The problem is when a scan is being performed, it reads the barcode perfect but enters and opens up previous loaded pages.

Anyone any help concerning the barcode scanning problem?
I'm scanning it into a textbox & it automatically hits the numbers into the address bar for some reason.

```
<form method="post" action="?action=orderscanpos">
<fieldset>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr><td align="left">Ordernummer:</td><td align="left"><input type="text" name="order_id"  value="<?php echo $scan; ?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="left"></td><td align="left"><input type="submit" name="cmd_up" value="order status updaten" /></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Without any code, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: i currently have this set up : 

<form method="post" action="?action=orderscanpos">
 <fieldset>
 <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr><td align="left">Ordernummer:</td><td align="left"><input type="text" name="order_id"  value="<?php echo $scan; ?>"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="left"></td><td align="left"><input type="submit" name="cmd_up" value="order status updaten" /></td></tr>
 </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>

Comment: Not here, please update the question with the code.

Comment: sorry, kinda new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Your barcode scanner is probably sending the `tab` key along with the data. Maybe check whether you can change that behaviour

Comment: that is true, onchange & block it ?
What would be a correct way of altering through the webpage?

Comment: Just my 2 cents: The character a reader sends before or after a read is called `sentinel`. May be this could help your search in modifying the sentinel.

Comment: @Yves I mean change the bar code reader's behaviour instead of programming a workaround for it (@Nirmal's hint sounds promising)

Answer (score 0):

Check the keyboard configuration details of the barcode reader, most can be configured to hit certain key combinations prior to the barcode info, maybe yours is configured to hit a key combination that causes that.